# Missing option USER FLOWS in Azure Active Directory B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm pretty new in Azure and I'm trying to integrate Azure AD B2C in my React app, and I have problems right in the beginning.
I'm trying to find

> USER FLOWS

option to configure sign up and sign on parts, but I cannot find it under the tab Polices as it shown in documentation
This where it should be accoriding to documentation :
[image]

Here is my screen of azure, with missing option policy:
[image]

I would really appreciate the help, how is this possible, where is user flow option?

Comment: I also have same problem, I even created a user flow but now I can not see that. @hardRock, Did you find any solution to your problem.

Comment: @CredibleAshok I solved it because person gave me right permission and then I could see everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the line in the screenshot:

"This is not an Azure AD B2C directory."

This is the Azure AD part of the tenant. Did you make a [B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant)?

If you have, make sure you select the [B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant#add-azure-ad-b2c-as-a-favorite-optional).

Comment: Person invited me to his directory where they already have B2C tenant. So I should modify user flows on his tenant, and this what I got. So in my account I don't have Azure AD B2C only in invited directory. Do you know how to choose existing B2C tenant from that directory?

Comment: They need to select their AAD B2C directory first in the AzurePortal Directory picker, then go to the Azure AD blade and invite you, and give you a directory role. They’ve invited you to the AAD that hosts the Azure Subscription where the AAD B2C lives, hence you don’t see the right screen.

Comment: Follow the exact step and let me know if your issue is still there.
1. Sign in to the Azure portal.

2.In the Azure portal menu, select All services.

3.In the All services search box, search for Azure AD B2C, hover over the search result, and then select the star icon in the tooltip. Azure AD B2C now appears in the Azure portal under Favorites.

4. If you want to change the position of your new favorite, go to the Azure portal menu, select Azure AD B2C, and then drag it up or down to the desired position.